# Adding Google Analytics Dashboard to Custom Post Type [WordPress]

Tags: php, wordpress, google-analytics

I have a theme in which I am attempting to add the plugin Google Analytics Dashboard's "sparkline" to the custom posts column. To make that a bit more clear, I need to add this:

[image]

To the columns here

[image]

And that's it! I'm just not well-versed with the PHP enough to know how to get this done. The analytics data appears out-of-the-box on all standard post types and some other custom ones, if that helps.

I would ask the developer for assistance, but he seems to have disappeared. Thanks in advance, and I'm hoping this is one of those quick, stupid situations where an easy answer can be shared with the greenhorn :)

Comment: its a great idea! hopefully somebody is building this.

Answer (score 0):

Hello,
If you want to program solution by yourself of your team-it is not easy. You should use Google Analytics API for PHP. It is not possible to describe it at small peace of text,but, may be, following links will be helpful for you and your developer:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreDevguide
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/downloads/list
https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/reporting

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for, here! I don't need to add it in terms of functionality, I need to have this custom post type display the standard default `post_column`. No need for APIs, I just don't know what PHP to use. So, not "add" as in introduce, but literally "add to."